# Анимация с реверсом и паузой

Tags: анимация, keyframes

Реализую покадровую анимацию на keyframes. Нужно чтобы при наведении мыши анимация проиграла до конца и остановилась, а при отведении мыши - чтобы анимация проиграла в обратную сторону. При этом если мышь отвели раньше, чем анимация закончилась, то она тут же должна начать проигрываться в обратную сторону.

Это вообще реально? Если нужно будет отказаться от keyframes, то подойдет и такой вариант. Что посоветуете?

Comment: А какая именно анимация должна быть?

Comment: Покадровая. Или о чем идет речь?

Comment: Я имел ввиду какие трансформации происходят с элементом, к которому применяется анимация?

Comment: Смещение bacground-position по вертикали.